# ios open app after screen unlock

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm developing a business app for iOS which will be used by customers in a cafeteria for ordering various products available.

Whenever iPad is screen unlocked by the customer, the custom business app should open up even if the previous customer open a different app.

So basically open this business app after every screen unlock, is it possible to get this done and how?

Answer (score 0):

no it's no. it's the default iOS behavior. Only in a jailbroken iPad you'll manage to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do, not possible to do that scenario

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.Its not possible and the other thing if you do so user gets irritated by seeing it again and again..As per my knowledge its not possible as well as not a better idea to do it..Think from user perspective..

Comment: it is possible :) The thing you want is the one I don't want.